# Using words tagged with \textsc{...} to make an index

Tags: small-caps, makeindex

During my thesis writing process, I am using smallcaps for proper nouns, acronyms and definitions. I think they are the main core of the document.

I know that exists the possibility to do an index at the end of the document coding `\index{word}` as it is explained in https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Indexing.

I have edited a lot of words inside the document as a `\textsc{sampleword}` to visualize them as a smallcaps. Now I'm interested in doing a word `index` at the end of the document with all these smallcaps I've used in the document. Is it possible?

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass{report}
\captionsetup{labelfont=\rmdefault, textfont=\rmdefault }
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\newcommand{\noun}[1]{\textsc{#1}}

\graphicspath{ {figures/} }
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
% the front matter
% chapters section
% the back matter
\clearpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliografía}
\bibliography{mendeley}
\include{endmatter/colophon}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\newcommand{\noun}[1]{\index{#1}\textsc{#1}}`

Comment: If you want the listing in the index to be in smallcaps use `\index{word@\textsc{word}}`. The part before the `@` tells `makeindex` how to sort the word and the part after tells LaTeX how to print it.

Comment: Please make it a working example. For example `\captionsetup` needs some package.

Comment: @egreg it works! :__) Is it possible to make the numbers of the pages linkables?

Comment: @egreg Do you want to answer? Juan: regarding your last comment, I guess you're after `\usepackage{hyperref}` (which you have probably found out by now).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments.